# Getting OAUTH_TOKEN_INVALID on a very simple Google Adwords PHP app

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-ads-api

I have tried to create a very simple test on top of Google Adwords PHP Library to create an AdWordsUser and access the Campaigns services.

I have an approved developer token, I have obtained a `client_id` and `client_secret` from Google Cloud Console, I have obtained also an `access_token` and `user_token`.

I added all this data into my `auth.ini` file but my app is failing with this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] [AuthenticationError.OAUTH_TOKEN_INVALID @ ; trigger:''] in /home/kaosmic/www/adwords/src/Google/Api/Ads/Common/Lib/AdsSoapClient.php:216 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/kaosmic/www/adwords/src/Google/Api/Ads/Common/Lib/AdsSoapClient.php(216): SoapClient->__soapCall('get', Array, NULL, Array, Array) 
#1 /home/kaosmic/www/adwords/src/Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/v201309/CampaignService.php(6208): AdsSoapClient->__soapCall('get', Array) 
#2 /home/kaosmic/www/adwords/tests/AdWordsIntegrationTest.php(77): CampaignService->get(Object(Selector)) 
#3 /home/kaosmic/www/adwords/tests/test.php(12): AdWordsIntegrationTest->testIntegrationCheckUserAgent() 
#4 {main} thrown in /home/kaosmic/www/adwords/src/Google/Api/Ads/Common/Lib/AdsSoapClient.php on line 216
```

I thought that maybe the token are expired so I regenerated them but it didn't help. 
Do you have any idea?

Thank you,
Anca

Comment: do you extend the token via a second call?

Comment: Could you please paste some more of your code for us to look at

Comment: Probably you got it already but did you make sure you are using the right token? There is an access token and a refresh token. When I started this gave me the nightmares... Check here maybe https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#exchange-authorization-code

Answer (score 0):

There is a more deep link between your refresh token and the developer token. If you use the same refresh token/OAuth token with a different developer token they will be invalidated and can't even use it with the original developer token. Posting for others out there wondering why their Oauth/refresh tokens are invalidated suddenly.

Best!
Makanist